# Sum of all HTML field values not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel-blade

I have nearly 100 HTML drop downs within 1 form, and before submission, I would like to calculate the sum of the selected values from all dropdown boxes. Currently, it is not working.

**jQuery:**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

  $(function () {
      var fields = $('#addFullAuditReport :input').change(calculate);

      function calculate() {
          var score = 0;
          fields.each(function () {
              score += +$(this).val();
          })
           $('#price').html(score.toFixed(2));
      }
  })

  </script>
```

HTML Form field example:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-1">1.4</div>
    <label for="1.4" class="col-sm-4 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <select class="form-control" id="input" name="1_4">
        <option value="0">No</option>
        <option value="10">Yes</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**HTML output**

```
Total : <u id="price"></u>
```

**Form initiation:**

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => array('addFullHandHygieneAudit'), 
'role'=>'form','id'=>'addFullHandHygieneAudit', 'class'=>'form-horizontal')) !!}
```

My problem is that nothing is adding to the HTML output. The jQuery could be correct, but I can't verify it until it's added to the field.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No `input` elements appear in `form` ; change selector to `parentElement #input` , e.g.; `$(".form-group #input")` . Also , substitute `score.toFixed(2)` for `price.toFixed(2)`

```js
$(function() {
    var fields = $(".form-group #input").change(calculate);

    function calculate() {
      var score = 0;
      fields.each(function() {
        score += +$(this).val();
      })
      $('#price').html(score.toFixed(2));
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-1">1.4</div>
  <label for="1.4" class="col-sm-4 control-label"></label>
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <select class="form-control" id="input" name="1_4">
      <option value="0">No</option>
      <option value="10">Yes</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

Total : <u id="price"></u>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a typo, change

```
$('#price').html(price.toFixed(2));
```

To

```
$('#price').html(score.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: Apologies, I too just noticed it. I've amended this and the issue is still apparent where the field is not updating.

Answer (score 0):

You should try sth like this

```
$(function () {
      var fields = $('select').change(calculate);

      function calculate() {
          var score = 0;
          fields.each(function () {
              var val = $(this).val();
              score += isNaN(val) ? 0 : parseFloat(val);
          })
           $('#price').html(score.toFixed(2));
      }
      calculate();
  })
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This code shows this error within the console - [Error] TypeError: score.toFixed is not a function. (In 'score.toFixed(2)', 'score.toFixed' is undefined).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can use the change event handler like this. My suggestion is this:

```
$(function ()
    {
    $('#addFullAuditReport :input').change(function()
        {
        var fields = $('#addFullAuditReport :input');
        var score = 0;

        fields.each(function() {
            score += $(this).val();
            });

        $('#price').html(score.toFixed(2));
        }
    });
```